# Jmeter Sequencing A Flow -Multiple Threads (Using REST API Token )

Tags: java, rest, jmeter

I am trying to test following scenario using Jmeter.

```
Step 1. Login Request (Which returns a Token) 
Step 2. Calling One.API which uses the Token Returned in Step 1. 
Step 3. Calling Two.API which uses the Token Returned in Step 1. 
Step 4. Logout.
```

I am able to achieve the above scenario with one thread everything works fine.

Now my requirement is to run the same stuff for 10 Users.

```
1. So 10 Login Requests should get performed.
2. 10 Calls to One.API should be made using 10 Different Tokens Generated. Token should not repeated for any of the Calls to API.
3. 10 Calls to Two.API should be made using 10 Different Tokens Generated. Token should not be repeated to any of the Calls to API.
4. 10 Log Out Request.
```

I tried assign multiple token, for example token1,token2,token 3 etc, but can I use the same with One.API Dynamically, as I am using a HTTP Header where I am passing the Token as Header Value.
Something like below is not working.

```
X-Auth-Token Value assigned ${$Token${__threadNum}}
```

But dynamic variable names does not seems to be working, is there any other way of doing the same stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work that way, JMeter doesn't support nested variable reference, you need to use one [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) or [__evalVar()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) function like:

- `${__V(token${__threadNum})}`

or

- `${__evalVar(token${__threadNum})}`

so composite variable value could be evaluated.

[image: Nested function variable]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for advanced information on above and more JMeter functions.

Comment: i have the same problem but i still can't do it :( i use HTTP Header Manager with this param `Authorization:  Token token=${__evalVar(token${__threadNum})}` and within the HTTP Request i use Regular Expression to get the token like that **Name** = `${__V(token${__threadNum})}` **Expression** = `"token": "([^"]+?)"`   what should i do? :'(